# Split Column with delimiter into multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I got a table with 20 columns. One of the columns contains multiple values separated by a semicolon. It looks like this:

```
-9;-9;-1;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-1;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-1;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-1;-9;-1;-9;-9;-9;-1;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-1;-1;-1;-1;-9;-1;-1;-9;-9;-9;-9;-1;-9;-1;-9;-9;-9;-1;-9;-1;-9;-1;-9;-9;-9;-9;-1;-9;-9;-1;-1;-9;-1;-1;0000;FFF8;-9;-9;-9;-1;-9;-1;-9;FFF6;-9;-1;-9;-1;-9;-1;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9
```

It contains always 115 values. The values can be "-1", "-9" or a hex number.

Now I want to create a view which contains the original 20 columns plus 115 columns foreach delimited string. Can someone help me?

Comment: Tough luck. New to SQL and supposed to deal with data stored like that.

Comment: What SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: sql server 2012

Comment: can you give output of your requirement,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example on how to do this:

```
DECLARE @tt TABLE(i INT IDENTITY,x VARCHAR(8000));
INSERT INTO @tt(x)VALUES('-9;-9;-1;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-1;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-1;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-1;-9;-1;-9;-9;-9;-1;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-1;-1;-1;-1;-9;-1;-1;-9;-9;-9;-9;-1;-9;-1;-9;-9;-9;-1;-9;-1;-9;-1;-9;-9;-9;-9;-1;-9;-9;-1;-1;-9;-1;-1;0000;FFF8;-9;-9;-9;-1;-9;-1;-9;FFF6;-9;-1;-9;-1;-9;-1;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9');

SELECT
    i,
    val1=n.v.value('/e[1]','VARCHAR(16)'),
    val2=n.v.value('/e[2]','VARCHAR(16)'),
    val3=n.v.value('/e[3]','VARCHAR(16)'),
    -- ... repeat for val4 .. val114
    val115=n.v.value('/e[115]','VARCHAR(16)')
FROM
    @tt
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT 
            CAST('<e>'+REPLACE(x,';','</e><e>')+'</e>' AS XML) AS itm
    ) AS i
    CROSS APPLY i.itm.nodes('/') AS n(v);
```

This is some XML trickery, by making the column with delimited values a XML where each value is an `e` element. The individual elements are then retrieved using the index in the `value` function.

Since this is a single statement it can be used as the query in a view.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a split function that returns the position. Unfortunately, `split_string()` in SQL Server 2016 does not yet support this.  ([Microsoft is aware of this.](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/2433171))

You can find code for such functions (say, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco), although I don't recommend that particular version).

Then you can do:

```
select t.*, v.*
from t cross apply
     (select max(case when pos = 1 then val end) as col_001,
             max(case when pos = 2 then val end) as col_002,
             . . .
             max(case when pos = 115 then val end) as col_115
      from dbo.split(';', t.col) s(pos, val)
     ) v;
```

Comment: i use sql server 2012

Answer (score 0):

You can query as below:

```
Declare @cols2 varchar(max)
Declare @query nvarchar(max)

--Row Numbers with tally
;with c1 as (
    Select top(Select max(len(splitcolumn) - len(replace(splitcolumn,';',''))) from #data) 
        RowN = Row_number() over (order by (Select NULL))
    from master..spt_values s1, master..spt_values 
)
select @cols2 = stuff((select ','+QuoteName(RowN) from c1 group by RowN for xml path('')),1,1,'')

Select @query = '
    Select * from (
        Select Id, RowN, [Value] from #data
        cross apply (
                Select xm = CAST(''<x>'' + REPLACE((SELECT REPLACE(splitcolumn,'';'',''$$$SSText$$$'') AS [*] FOR XML PATH('''')),''$$$SSText$$$'',''</x><x>'')+ ''</x>'' AS XML) 
        ) a
        cross apply (
            Select RowN = Row_Number() over (order by (SELECT NULL)), y.value(N''text()[1]'', N''nvarchar(MAX)'') as value 
            FROM a.xm.nodes(N''x'') as x(y) 
        ) b
    ) rws
    pivot (max([Value]) for RowN in (' + @cols2 + ')) p'

Exec sp_executesql @query
```